# Dynamically creating a UIPageControl on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, controls, ios4

I'm new with objective-c (and obviously iphone development) and I have to dynamically create UI layout of my aplication, to be more precise I have to create N (3 for example) different views which are connected with UIPageControl ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). After that, I have to add various dynamically created controls on created views. Any suggestions? some links? (maybe links on whole topic on dynamicall creation of controls?) or is it possible? can I achive same functionallity on some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example of Page control is the PageControl sample code available on developer.apple.com. In the UIPageControl link you have in your question, just refer to 'Related sample code' section to download and look at the PageControl source code.